# Hierarchical cache in Django

Tags: django, caching

What I want to do is to mark some values in the cache as related so I could delete them at once. For example when I insert a new entry to the database I want to delete everything in the cache which was based on the old values in database.

I could always use cache.clear() but it seems too brutal to me. Or I could store related values together in the dictionary and cache this dictionary. Or I could maintain some kind of index in an extra field in cache. But everything seems to complicated to me (eventually slow?).

What you think? Is there any existing solution? Or is my approach wrong? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the cache api? It sounds like it.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995126/invalidating-a-path-from-the-django-cache-recursively), which pointed me to [these slides](http://www.slideshare.net/adorepump/accelerate-your-rails-site-with-automatic-generationbased-action-caching) helped me create a nice generational caching system which let me create the hierarchy I wanted.

In short, you store a generation key (such as `group`) in your cache and incorporate the value stored into your key creation function so that you can invalidate a whole set of keys at once.

With this basic concept you could create highly complex hierarchies or just a simple group system.

For example:

```
class Cache(object):
    def generate_cache_key(self, key, group=None):
        """
        Generate a cache key relating them via an outside source (group)
        Generates key such as 'group-1:KEY-your-key-here'

        Note: consider this pseudo code and definitely incomplete code.
        """
        key_fragments = [('key', key)]

        if group:
            key_fragments.append((group, cache.get(group, '1')))

        combined_key = ":".join(['%s-%s' % (name, value) for name, value in key_fragments)

        hashed_key = md5(combined_key).hexdigest()
        return hashed_key


    def increment_group(self, group):
        """
        Invalidate an entire group
        """
        cache.incr(group)


    def set(self, key, value, group=None):
        key = self.generate_cache_key(key, group)
        cache.set(key, value)


    def get(self, key, group=None):
        key = self.generate_cache_key(key, group)
        return cache.get(key)

# example
>>> cache = Cache()
>>> cache.set('key', 'value', 'somehow_related')
>>> cache.set('key2', 'value2', 'somehow_related')
>>> cache.increment_group('somehow_related')
>>> cache.get('key') # both invalidated
>>> cache.get('key2') # both invalidated
```

Comment: Wow, that's smart! I guess it's not a problem that old values are not actually deleted...?

Comment: The slides I point to up there simply say memcached clears out the oldest keys first when it runs out of memory. I'm not sure what the real world improvement would be for removing those keys and preventing old but otherwise good keys from going first. I would optimize that last..

Comment: This stores the group's current version number in the cache. I suppose this works fine if the cache flushes by age of last get or set operation, but if it uses some other method, isn't it possible the group's current version gets flushed so it resets to 1 and you can get stale data from the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Caching a dict or something serialised (with JSON or the like) sounds good to me. The cache backends are key-value stores like memcache, they aren't hierarchical.

Comment: Well it sounds good to me too but imagine a situation when I would cache for example 50 pages in HTML. Loading/storing each one of them would mean to load all 50 pages first. Is cache that fast and unlimited to handle that?

Comment: OK, not in that case. Here is another approach: make the cache keys for your pages depend on a few page-specific variables. These variables can be in the database, and they can be cached with a short expiration. Page churn should be low, you can let pages with old keys expire over a longer time.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, it's very interesting. But I'm probably going to use the solution in the next answer which suits more my needs.

Comment: My suggestion is mostly the same as Yuji's answer, anyway. The old values are deleted, see the docs about expiration (the default is 5 minutes).